# Find the country which has most employees are from SQL

Tags: sql, rdbms

Employee_Details(EmployeeID ,FirstName,LastName ,Place,Country ,PhoneNo)

SQL:How I find the country which has most employees are from?

Comment: In order to get a relevant answer, you should [edit] your question and add the tag for the DBMS you are using. Is it MySQL? Is it SQL Server? Is it SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNTRY,COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEEID ) AS EMP_COUNT 
FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS 
GROUP BY COUNTRY 
ORDER BY EMP_COUNT DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I found the answer. Thank you respond to my question.

Comment: @Dananjaya maybe you would like to share your answer so as to help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
 SELECT b.country
        , COUNT(a.employeeid) AS count
    FROM   Employee_Details a
          INNER JOIN Employee_Detailsb ON a.country = b.country
    GROUP BY b.country
    HAVING COUNT(employeeid) >100;
```

100, i have given for reference but you can give what you want here.

Comment: ok,I found the answer. Thank you respond to my question.